# Performing join operation on 3 tables using knex

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, knex.js

I have a SQL query which performs `innerJoin` operation on 2 tables.

Table 1: `user`

[image]

Table 2: `local_auth`

[image]

The query returns all the matching rows based on the `user_id` key

```
async getUser(id) {
    return camelizeKeys(
        await knex
        .select(
            'u.id',
            'u.first_name',
            'u.last_name',
            'u.username',
            'u.image_url',
            'u.is_admin',
            'u.phone',
            'u.info',
            'la.email'
        )
        .from('user AS u')
        .leftJoin('local_auth AS la', 'la.user_id', 'u.id')
        .where('u.id', '=', id)
        .first()
    );
}
```

Now, what I have to do is to modify the above query so that it performs the join operation on 3 tables.

Table 3: `customer_user`

[image]

There is another table called `customer_user`, which has `user_id` as one of the foreign key. How do I retrieve some fields from `customer_user` table based on the `user_id`. I would like to perform something like this (but of course the following won’t work due to the incorrect way of performing multiple joins using knex)

```
async getUser(id) {
    return camelizeKeys(
        await knex
        .select(
            'u.id',
            'u.first_name',
            'u.last_name',
            'u.username',
            'u.image_url',
            'u.is_admin',
            'u.phone',
            'u.info',
            'la.email',
            'cu.customer_id',
            'cu.department_id'
        )
        .from('user AS u')
        .leftJoin('local_auth AS la', 'la.user_id', 'u.id')
        .leftJoin('customer_user AS cu', 'cu.user_id', 'u.id')
        .where('u.id', '=', id)
        .first()
    );
}
```

Note: Due to the limitation of adding a `table` markup on SO, I have attached the screenshot instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, the query works just fine. Due to syntax error, I wasn't able to execute it

```
async getUser(id) {
    return camelizeKeys(
        await knex
        .select(
            'u.id',
            'u.first_name',
            'u.last_name',
            'u.username',
            'u.image_url',
            'u.is_admin',
            'u.phone',
            'u.info',
            'la.email',
            'cu.customer_id',
            'cu.department_id'
        )
        .from('user AS u')
        .leftJoin('local_auth AS la', 'la.user_id', 'u.id')
        .leftJoin('customer_user AS cu', 'cu.user_id', 'u.id')
        .where('u.id', '=', id)
        .first()
    );
}
```

Comment: could you please let me know, how to add multiple conditions on left join? like userid = id AND departmentid = deptid in query?

Comment: @Codebrekers use a function as the second parameter to the join function, and use on() and andOn. Ex: `knex.select('*').from('users').join('accounts', function() {
  this.on('accounts.id', '=', 'users.account_id').andOn('accounts.owner_id', '=', 'users.id')
})` Source: http://knexjs.org/#Builder-join